# How to sort a an arraylist of strings by frequency of each element and remove the duplications?

Tags: java, arraylist

I hava an arraylist of strings

> aa,bbb,ccc,ddd,aaa,aaa,aaa,vv,bbb,ggg,....

Is there any fast possibility to sort it by frequency and delete all duplicate elements?

What I got now is that I create a new arraylist, where:

so from the example above :

> aa,1  bbb,2 ccc,1 ddd,1 aaa,3 aaa,3 aaa,3 vv,1 bbb,2 ggg,1 ...

I would like to get the following:

> aaa,3 bbb,2 aa,1 ccc,1 ddd,1 vv,1 ggg,1

my code so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i< arr_All_Items.size();i++)    
{
 new_Items.add(newItem_in_arr(arr_All_Items.get(i).toString(),Collections.frequency(arr_All_Items, arr_All_Items.get(i).toString())));
}
```

How to sort in descending order `new_items`?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an arrayList, you could use a Map object of Strings and Integers. The key would be the string, and the object they correspond to are the frequency of that string.  It would allow for only one of each type, and you could get the data you want easily.

An alternative is you could create an object that contains the string and frequency, and have a comparator based on the frequency of that object.

Answer (score 0):

```
int frequencyLimit = 0;
// substitute Object for the specific type the array houses
for(Object o : arr_All_Items) {
    int newFrequency = Collections.frequency(arr_All_Items, o.toString());
    if(newFrequency > frequencyLimit) {
        frequencyLimit = newFrequency;
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < arr_All_Items.size(); i++) {
    // if item does not exist in the new array
    if(!(new_Items.contains(arr_All_Items.get(i).toString()))) {
        new_Items.add(newItem_in_arr(arr_All_Items.get(i).toString(), frequencyLimit -
            Collections.frequency(arr_All_Items, arr_All_Items.get(i).toString()));
    }
}
```

This should insert the objects into the list based on a priority equal to their frequency. If the highest frequency is 10, then the object with that frequency will be placed at index 0 (10 - 10).

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but tell me ,shouldnt it be :new_Items.add (index, element). maybe i am missing something . what is newItem_in_arr ?

Comment: Not working , it works only for the most frequent item , it wil lbe placed in index 0 , all others are not placed correctly .

Answer (score 0):

Using Collections.frequency() (probably) has quadratic performance in the length of the list, which isn't ideal if your list is long. You can do it in linear time though:

(This is typed directly into SO, so probably has some stupid mistakes. The gist is right though.)

Create a class that represents a string and a count. Better: use a generic, to avoid tying yourself to a string:

```
public class Datum<T>
{
  private final T t;
  private int count;

  public Datum (final T t)
  {
    this.t = t;
    this.count = 0;
  }


  public void increment ()
  {
    ++count;
  }


  public boolean matches (final T t)
  {
    return (null == this.t) ? (null == t) || this.t.equals (t);
  }


  public int getCount () { return count; }
  public T getValue () { return t; }
}
```

Loop through your list of strings, populating a Map>:

```
final Map<String, Datum<String>> map = new HashMap<> ();

for (final String str: yourList)
{
  Datum<T> datum = map.get (str);
  if (null == datum)
  {
    datum = new Datum<String> (str);
    map.put (str, datum);
  }

  datum.increment ();
}
```

Dump your Datum<> instances into an ArrayList<>:

```
final List<Datum<String>> data = new ArrayList<> (map.values ());
```

Sort using a Comparator that compares the count members:

```
class DatumComparator<T> implements Comparator<T>
{
  @Override
  public int compare (final Datum<T> t1, final Datum<T> t2)
  {
    // reverse this to reverse the sort order.
    return t2.getCount () - t1.getCount ();
  }
}

Collections.sort (data, new DatumComparator<String> ());
```

Print:

```
for (final Datum<String> datum: data)
{
  System.out.println (datum.getValue () + ", " + datum.getCount ());
}
```